# Abstract and Final class defined on the same Scala Class

Tags: java, scala, class, abstract, final

I know that Scala allows both `abstract` and `final` on the same class.
What is the benefit of this?
Example:

```
final abstract class Parent { ... }
```

The above code compiles fine. When comparing this to Java, it is not allowed.
Also, is there any logic in defining both?

Comment: Hmm. Can that class still have a companion object?

Comment: @Idos: When suggesting edits, please don't introduce `<br>` tags. Either use two spaces instead, or better, start a new paragraph if a line break is really needed.

Answer (score 4):

`abstract` forbids instantiation (`new`...), whereas `final` forbids subclassing              
(`new Class { ... }`), so they both serve a different purpose here.

An example class like this in Scala is `Int`, which is represented by the *primitive integer* type of the JVM. Because it's primitive type on runtime and the fact that the JVM doesn't allow adding new primitives, there is no legal way to extend this type.
 Also there is no way to instantiate it other than by giving a literal (e.g. `val value: Int = 5`).

Comment: Aside from the "built-in" classes, like `Int`, what is the use of this? What can you do with a class that can be neither subclassed nor instantiated? Any examples?